# Span horizontal icon bar when clicking on an icon in a vertical icon bar

Tags: css, iconmenu

I want to span horizontal icon bar when clicking on an icon in a vertical icon bar.
For example, in the image below, clicking on the 3rd icon from the bottom (in the red box) in the vertical icon bar, will show the horizontal icon bar (in the red box) in the same line of the clicked icon.
Which layout options (e.g. grid) should I use to achieve this?

Thanks

---

EDIT

I updated Damian Chudobiński's answer to refer to actual icons, and followed SebastianK advice to use `transform: translateX(-100%)`.
[In the updated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77138051/span-horizontal-icon-bar-when-clicking-on-an-icon-in-a-vertical-icon-bar/77147125#77147125), the verical icon bar is positioned on the right side and the horizontal icon bar spans to the left, starting from the right.
This solved my problem.
Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Show what you have tried so we may best assist you here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Add event listeners to toggle the active class on li elements
const iconListItems = document.querySelectorAll('.icon-list li');

iconListItems.forEach((item) =>
{
  item.addEventListener('click', () =>
  {
    document.querySelectorAll('.icon-list li').forEach((mainItem) =>
    {
        mainItem.classList.remove('active');
        item.classList.add('active');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.icon-list
{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* height: 100vh; */
}

.icon-list li
{
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-list li:hover
{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

/* Style for the icons */
.icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Expand the nested list on hover or click */
.icon-list li:hover .nested-list,
.icon-list li.active .nested-list
{
  display: flex;
}

/* Style for the nested list */
.nested-list
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  z-index: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

/* Style for subpage items */
.nested-list li
{
  margin-right: 5px;
  word-wrap: no-wrap;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="icon-list">
        <li>
            <div class="icon">I1</div>
            <ul class="nested-list">
                <li><i class="fa fa-file" style="font-size:32px;"></i></i>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="icon">I2</div>
            <ul class="nested-list">
                <li><i class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:32px;"></i></i>
                <li><i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:32px;"></i></i>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="icon">I3</div>
            <ul class="nested-list">
                <li><i class="fa fa-cloud" style="font-size:32px;"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:32px;"></i></i>
                <li><i class="fa fa-file" style="font-size:32px;"></i></i>
                <li><i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:32px;"></i></i>
                <li><i class="fa fa-bars" style="font-size:32px;"></i></i>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

By myself i would like to go into some flex'es it's have not that bad support
https://caniuse.com/?search=flex

Some quick code

```js
// Add event listeners to toggle the active class on li elements
const iconListItems = document.querySelectorAll('.icon-list li');

iconListItems.forEach((item) =>
{
  item.addEventListener('click', () =>
  {
    var wasAlreadyActive = item.classList.contains('active');
    document.querySelectorAll('.icon-list li').forEach((mainItem) =>
    {
        mainItem.classList.remove('active');
    });
    
    if(! wasAlreadyActive)
    {
        item.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
});

document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) =>
{
    if (!event.target.closest('.icon-list'))
    {
        // If the click is outside of the icon list, close all nested lists
        iconListItems.forEach((item) =>
        {
            item.classList.remove('active');
        });
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.icon-list
{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-list li
{
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-list li:hover
{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

/* Style for the icons */
.icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Expand the nested list on hover or click */
.icon-list li:hover .nested-list,
.icon-list li.active .nested-list
{
  display: flex;
}

/* Style for the nested list */
.nested-list
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  z-index: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

/* Style for subpage items */
.nested-list li
{
  margin-right: 5px;
  word-wrap: no-wrap;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <ul class="icon-list">
        <li>
            <div class="icon">I1</div>
            <ul class="nested-list">
                <li>
                    <div>Icon</div>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#">Subpage 1.1</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="icon">I2</div>
            <ul class="nested-list">
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 2.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="icon">I3</div>
            <ul class="nested-list">
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.7</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

How about something like this

```js
// Add event listeners to toggle the active class on li elements
const iconListItems = document.querySelectorAll('.icon-list li');

iconListItems.forEach((item) =>
{
  item.addEventListener('click', () =>
  {
    document.querySelectorAll('.icon-list li').forEach((mainItem) =>
    {
        mainItem.classList.remove('active');
        item.classList.add('active');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.icon-list
{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-list li
{
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-list li:hover
{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

/* Style for the icons */
.icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Expand the nested list on hover or click */
.icon-list li:hover .nested-list,
.icon-list li.active .nested-list
{
  display: flex;
}

/* Style for the nested list */
.nested-list
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  z-index: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

/* Style for subpage items */
.nested-list li
{
  margin-right: 5px;
  word-wrap: no-wrap;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <ul class="icon-list">
        <li>
            <div class="icon">I1</div>
            <ul class="nested-list">
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 1.1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="icon">I2</div>
            <ul class="nested-list">
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 2.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="icon">I3</div>
            <ul class="nested-list">
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subpage 3.7</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the horizontal  bar as a sibling to the vertical icon button (both inside a parent div), and use `position: absolute` together with `left: 0` and `transform: translateX(-100%)` to move the bar left of the icon.

The bar itself could be created with `display: flex`